# Why is my array.push() not pushing the correct values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding chess and trying to push a pseudo legal move into an array and before pushing I am logging it and it is correct and after pushing it is also correct but when I log the array it pushed the wrong thing.

```
if (this.colour == 'white') {
         this.moveOffsets.yOffset = -1 * tileSize;
      }
      else {
         this.moveOffsets.yOffset = 1 * tileSize;
      }
      pseudoLegalPos.length = 0;
      pseudoLegalPos.push(this.x, this.y + this.moveOffsets.yOffset);
      console.log(pseudoLegalPos);
      this.pseudoLegal.push(pseudoLegalPos);
      console.log(pseudoLegalPos);
}
```

Also when I log the array it ended up pushing a value that was supposed to be pushed later in the function.

Comment: `pseudoLegalPos.length = 0;` makes it seem like you are using the same thing over and over thinking when you push it you get a new copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that's in a loop, doing

```
pseudoLegalPos.length = 0;
pseudoLegalPos.push(...);
this.pseudoLegal.push(pseudoLegalPos);
```

will only push multiple copies of the same `pseudoLegalPos` array into `this.pseudoLegal`.

Chances are you want

```
const pos = [this.x, this.y + this.moveOffsets.yOffset];
this.pseudoLegal.push(pos);
```

instead for fresh new `pos`es.